# Reconhecer erro de envio de email Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, email, cron

Bom dia.
Estou fazendo uma cron com `Laravel 5.2` para envio de emails para minha empresa, estou utilizando o envio `Mail` do Laravel e gostaria de saber se existe uma forma do Laravel reconhecer que o email não existe ou reconhecer que ocorreu erro no envio pelo fato do email do destinário não existir quando fosse enviado.

Comment: Dá uma olhada nessa lib: https://github.com/skmetaly/laravel-smtp-email-verifier

Comment: vou dar uma olhada e já passo o feedback. Valeu

Comment: Seria isso mesmo @KayoBruno. Agora só vou configurar o meu servidor para fazer a verificação, pois por padrão ele vem configurado apenas o do google.com. Valeu brow